# Does Matthew 4:10 teach that only YHWH/Jehovah can be worshiped?

Tags: jesus, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, worship, tetragrammaton, deity

In Matthew 4, Satan shows Jesus "all the kingdoms of the world and their glory" (NKJV) and says that he'll give it all to Jesus if He would worship him (vv. 8-9). Jesus rejects this, saying, "Away with you, Satan! For it is written, ‘You shall worship the LORD your God, and Him only you shall serve’" (NKJV). The reason the New King James Version capitalizes "LORD" is because, in the originally quoted verse (apparently Deut. 6:13), the word used was *YHWH* (also known as *Jehovah*).

Does this mean that only YHWH/Jehovah can be worshiped? If so, this would have implications for the fact that, elsewhere in Scripture, Jesus accepts worship. Thanks!

Comment: Jesus is not seen by Christians as standing in opposition to God; worshipping and obeying him is equivalent to the latter, since he was sent by Him. For instance, if you obey and pay reverence to the king (as was often the case in ancient and medieval times), you also had to obey and pay reverence to his noblemen or soldiers (as opposed to those belonging to a rival king, for instance).

Comment: @The Editor. "the fact that, elsewhere in Scripture, Jesus accepts worship. Thanks!" Can you give the verses supporting this statement please?

Comment: @Lucian In Acts 10:25-26, the apostle Peter, a representative of Christ, refused to be worshiped because such was reserved for God. In Revelation 19:10 and 22:8-9, even angels, messengers of God, are not to be worshiped. Would this suggest that not even representatives are worthy of worship?

Comment: @AlexBalilo I'd direct you to Dottard's answer below. He lists such verses.

Comment: @The Editor. "I'd direct you to Dottard's answer below. He lists such verses" Do you have a verse you yourself use to support your statement "elsewhere in Scripture, Jesus accepts worship"? Was he worshiped as God almighty the Creator or was he shown obeissance?

Comment: The answer to your last question varies across Christian denominations; in Acts, the pagans, influenced by their polytheistic beliefs, were unwittingly trying to turn Paul and Barnabas into (rival) deities (to the one God); it's like someone whispering into a nobleman's or soldier's ear that they'd rather have them as king, instead of the current ruler; this is pure treason. In Daniel and Revelation, the statement was meant primarily for the audience, dwelling amongst pagans (Jews during the Babylonian captivity, and early gentile Christians). Also, a humble person always deflects compliments.

Comment: @AlexBalilo As Dottard's post shows, _proskuneó_ is used in reference to worship of the Father and of Jesus, but when it's used referencing Peter or an angel, it's condemned. Do you have any verses showing the Bible to use _proskuneó_ in reference to someone less than Deity? If so, which verses show this, and how is it to be reconciled with Matthew 4:10, which teaches that _proskuneó_ is reserved only for Jehovah God?

Comment: @Lucian How do you reconcile your understanding with Matthew 4:10, which teaches that _proskuneó_ is reserved only for Jehovah God? Doesn't it seem that giving _proskuneó_ to someone less than God is condemned by Matthew 4:10 and that this is why Peter refused it? Also, while the audience can certainly learn from the event, isn't the one that the angel addressed directly be John himself--not the audience?

Comment: @The Editor. Was Jesus worshipped as the Creator God or did people did obeissance to him? Did Jesus received the same kind of worship like the one cited in Matthew 4:10? If so, cite the verse.

Comment: @TheEditor: A text, and one's interpretation thereof, are ultimately two distinct things; as such, I don't see any need for reconciliation. Showing reverence to God's people or angels is part and parcel of obeying and respecting Him; if someone thanks another, and the latter replies by saying *oh, don't thank me*, or *oh, don't even mention it*, or *oh, it's nothing, really*, I'd feel inclined to interpret their gesture or response as a manifestation of selfless love, befitting beings made in God's image, rather than a denouncement of thankfulness as something evil.

Comment: @AlexBalilo The type of worship cited in Matthew 4:10 is _proskuneó_, and this is done to Jesus numerous times. Examples include Matthew 2:11, 28:9, etc. In fact, the term might be used for Jesus more than it is for anyone else. Since Matthew 4:10 says "only," do you have a verse showing that certain kinds of worship could be offered to humans or angels?

Comment: @Lucian Well, if it's true that, as you said, "a humble person always deflects compliments," why didn't Jesus ever deflect when He was worshiped, despite being worshiped numerous times, whereas Peter and the angels refused as soon as worship came to them? Was Jesus not humble (cf. Zec. 9:9; Matt. 11:29; John 13:5)? When the others said, "Do not worship me," it doesn't appear to be about humility, but rather that people really shouldn't be worshiping mere men or angels. If it's just about modesty, it'd seem that Jesus would redirect the worship to God as they did. Those are my thoughts, anyway.

Comment: @The Editor. "do you have a verse showing that certain kinds of worship could be offered to humans or angels?" See Revelation 3:9.

Comment: @TheEditor: For roughly the same reason God doesn't either.

Comment: @AlexBalilo I haven't considered Revelation 3:9 before. That seems to make sense.

Comment: @Lucian What's the reason that God doesn't?

Comment: @TheEditor: Because there are no alternatives to Him; there is no one else above Him to whom He can deflect.

Comment: @Lucian So in man or angel's case, they deflect to a higher source, but in God's case, He doesn't deflect because there is no higher source to deflect to. And you said that Jesus doesn't deflect "For roughly the same reason God doesn't either." In your understanding, then, does this likewise make Jesus (as well as the Father) the ultimate source of worship?

Comment: **(1).** *And you said that Jesus doesn't deflect* - Technically, you did. Sometimes, he does (Matthew 19:17, Mark 10:18, Luke 18:19). But many times he does not, and this was the situation that you were addressing earlier. **(2).** *In **your** understanding, then, does this likewise make Jesus (as well as the Father) the ultimate source of worship?* - In **my** understanding, it doesn't, since the Father is the ultimate source of everything, including the Son and the Spirit.

Comment: @Lucian When I asked why He never deflects, you answered, "For roughly the same reason God doesn't either," which I saw as a concession. Regarding Matthew 19:17, Mark 10:18, Luke 18:19, many see Jesus as not making a true deflection, as if He were less "Good" than God. In their view, He asks why he calls Him "Good" when only God is, perhaps to test if he'd see Jesus' divinity. Regardless, I'll drop that and instead ask: For the clear non-deflections, what did you mean in saying He didn't deflect "For roughly the same reason God doesn't either"? That there's no source above to deflect to?

Comment: @TheEditor: The qualifier *roughly* was meant to convey two ideas: on one hand, that he does *not always* deflect; and, on the other, that, though divine, even he himself has God as Father (source, root, origin), relating to Him as would a Word to a speaker. (Since this Q&A site strongly discourages extended conversations from taking place in the comment section, this will mark my last reply o this thread).

Answer (score 1):

It is true that in some version of the NKJV, "LORD" is fully capitalized in Matt 4:10, but only because the OT source, Deut 6:13, translated the tetragrammaton.

- Deut 6:13 (from Hebrew) - Fear the LORD your God, serve Him only, and take your oaths in His name.
- Deut 6:13 (from LXX) - Thou shalt fear the Lord thy God, and him only shalt thou serve; and thou shalt cleave to him, and by his name thou shalt swear.

This is consistent with other OT teaching including the first commandment, Ex 20:3, Deut 5:7, as repeated in other places such as Ex 34:14, Deut 8:19, 1 Kings 17:35-38, etc).

The matter at issue here is the intent of the verb προσκυνέω (proskuneó) and how it should be translated.  Most English versions simply translate it "worship".  BDAG offers a single meaning for this word:

> **to express in attitude or gesture one's complete dependence on or submission to a high authority figure, *(fall down and) worship, do
> obeisance to, prostrate oneself before, do reverence to, welcome
> respectfully***

There are several cases in the the NT where such behavior, with this specific verb, is forbidden to anyone by God, namely:

- Matt 4:10 - “Away from Me, Satan!” Jesus declared. “For it is written: ‘**Worship** the Lord your God and serve Him only.’ ”
- Luke 4:8 - But Jesus answered, “It is written: ‘**Worship** the Lord your God and serve Him only.’”
- Acts 10:25, 26 - As Peter was about to enter, Cornelius met him and fell at his feet to **worship** him. But Peter helped him up. “Stand up,” he said, “I am only a man myself.”
- Rev 19:10 - So I fell at his feet to **worship** him [the angel]. But he told me, “Do not do that! I am a fellow servant with you and your brothers who rely on the testimony of Jesus. Worship God! For the testimony of Jesus is the spirit of prophecy.”
- Rev 22:8, 9 - And when I had heard and seen them, I fell down to **worship** at the feet of the angel who had shown me these things. But he said to me, “Do not do that! I am a fellow servant with you and your brothers the prophets, and with those who keep the words of this book. **Worship** God!”

Thus, there is ample support for the OT passages that declare that only the LORD God is worthy of our worship:

- Ex 34:14 - Do not **worship** [προσκυνέω LXX] any other god, for the LORD, whose name is Jealous, is a jealous God.
- Deut 8:19 - If you ever forget the LORD your God and follow other gods and **worship** [προσκυνέω LXX] and bow down to them, I testify against you today that you will surely be destroyed.

In the NT we often find this same verb used of people worshiping Jesus such as: Matt 2:2, 8, 11, 8:2, 14:33, 15:25, 18:26, 20:20, 28:9, 17, 5:6, 15:19, Luke 24:52, John 9:38, Heb 1:6, Rev 5:14,

In fact, the largest portion of the occurrences of προσκυνέω are used to denote worship of Jesus, but some are used of worshiping the Father, such as John 4:23, 24, 1 Cor 14:25, Rev 11:16, etc.

Occasionally, it is used of someone offering false (illegal) worship of a false deity such as: Acts 7:23, Rev 9:20, 13:4, 8, 12, 15, 14:11, 16:2, etc.  In all these contexts, the worship of such false deities is condemned by the context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The expansive list of passages you gave supports the teaching that only the LORD (YHWH/Jehovah) is to be worshiped (Greek, _proskuneó_), and the weight of the usage for _proskuneó_ that you cited suggest that this very action is done for Jesus with HIs acceptance. Would this imply that Jesus is therefore YHWH/Jehovah (at least in some sense)?

Comment: @TheEditor - absolutely!  The same as the LORD is creator in the OT and Jesus is creator in the NT; same for savior; same for first and last; same for the Shepherd; same for "Lord of Lords; same for "Lord of All", same for the Bridegroom, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Jehovah God is the only one we should worship.  That is the essence of the first commandment.

> Thou shalt have no other gods before me. (Exodus 20:3, KJV)

To worship anyone or anything else is to break this commandment.

The Bible is clear that we have only one true God, who is identified, in the New Testament, as being the Father.

> But to us there is but one God, the Father, of whom are all things,
> and we in him; and one Lord Jesus Christ, by whom are all things, and
> we by him. (1 Corinthians 8:6, KJV)
>
> Blessed be God, even the Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Father
> of mercies, and the God of all comfort; (2 Corinthians 1:3)

But the Father is in Jesus, and when we worship at Jesus' feet, it is not his humanity that we are worshiping, but the divinity of the Father who is in him.  This is acceptable worship.

> Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and the Father in me? the
> words that I speak unto you I speak not of myself: but the Father that
> dwelleth in me, he doeth the works. Believe me that I am in the
> Father, and the Father in me: or else believe me for the very works'
> sake. (John 14:10-11, KJV)

Even the very words that Jesus spoke were those of the Father.

> He that loveth me not keepeth not my sayings: and the word which ye
> hear is not mine, but the Father's which sent me. (John 14:24, KJV)

And it was to the Father whom Jesus directed his disciples to pray.  It was the Father whom Jesus called "the only true God" in his prayer.

> These words spake Jesus, and lifted up his eyes to heaven, and said,
> Father, the hour is come; glorify thy Son, that thy Son also may
> glorify thee: ...
> And this is life eternal, that they might know thee the only true God,
> and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent. (John 17:1,3, KJV)

Because Jesus' flesh veiled the presence of the Father within him (see Hebrews 10:20), no one has seen God (see John 1:18).  But we can worship the Father, the divinity in Christ, without seeing the Father in him.

God is not a man (see Numbers 23:19) and whereas, as a man, Jesus was tempted in the wilderness (see Matthew 4:1), God cannot be and was not tempted (see James 1:13).  On the cross, the immortal God (see 1 Timothy 6:16) did not die, but Jesus, in his human flesh, did die.  When we worship Jesus, we acknowledge the Divinity within him.

Comment: _when we worship at Jesus' feet ... we are worshiping ... the divinity of the Father who is in him_ (Quote) So, in that case, not worshipping  the _Person_ of the Son at all : it would seem.